# What evidence is there to support or refute the assertion that The Doctor is a Super Hero?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor fits all superhero requirements, and many of of the tropes.

His family is dead, he is the last of his race (Superman-esqué), and he goes around saving people and helping mankind.

Furthermore, he has the "power" to regenerate, he has the "power" to travel through space and time with his TARDIS (remember Batman can use his gadgets).

The only difference is that many of the incarnations of The Doctor don't use violence.

So, what evidence is there to support or refute the assertion that The Doctor is a Super Hero? And how, if at all, does this vary amongst his different regenerations?

Comment: Hi Brad, and welcome to this site. Your questions strikes me as requiring discussion, rather than seeking a definitive answer. So I'm going to vote to put it on hold as this site is dedicated not to board-like discussion but definitive answers. Maybe you could clarify what you actually mean, in case I misread. If the question meets the criteria for objectivity of this site, it will be reopened.

Comment: This is a very thought-provoking question, and I hope it can be modified to fit the site's criteria. [The help part of the site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help), with its pages on [What topics can I ask here?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) may be useful. And once you have 20+ rep, please join us in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)! We can talk about this *there* even if it can't fit into a nice neat question on the main site.

Comment: I think saying the Doctor doesn't use violence is something *thoroughly* debunked by a lot of the new seasons. He may not carry a gun or punch his enemies, but the violence around him sure ain't coincidental.

Comment: Define "superhero".

Comment: The answer also varies widely from Doctor to Doctor.

Comment: Too bad the question is on hold.  Everything here has to be argumented on facts reported in the concerned stories. This can be too.  My own conclusion is that he cannot be a superhero because he is not American. Is that enough for a definitive answer ?  Though of course, the reasonning may be questionned.

Comment: Why does a superhero have to be American?
I don't see how this is a constructive question regardless.

Comment: I'm new to this site but not to SE, and I agree with @babou. I think this is a fascinating question (though I also agree with Phoshi that the Doctor definitely does use violence--once he even *did* carry a gun!) It would also be interesting to compare old-Who and new-Who, as the "last of his race" criterion didn't apply before the Time War ended. I'd love to read (and write!) answers to this question.

Comment: Yes, it's an interesting question, but it's subjective and going to lead to discussion. People will have different ideas about what exactly the criteria for being considered a super hero are.

Comment: I've suggested an edit which triesd to make this question a less opinion based, alas at the expense of making it more *list* like. Further suggestions to improve it would be great, as I would really like to see some answers to this question.

Comment: @MarkBooth: I think the problem is that the definition of super hero is a tad fuzzy. So, it doesn't seem constructive to ask for evidence, if we already cannot agree what we're trying to establish. Maybe one could ask to enumerate qualities he *does* share with existing super heroes, but that would also be an (off-topic) list question.

Comment: "_... answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions ..._"  - Says WHO ?

Comment: @babou - Because 'Superhero' in this use is a subjective term.  'Per the definitions of the DC universe, would he be one' might not be.. But in the Whovian Universe, 'Super Hero' is not an objectively defined term.

Comment: Superhero?...Blimey.. I don't that I'd say that.. but then again...